# App theme changing to Default System theme when coming back from System Settings

Tags: android

Actually, I need to check if the notification is blocked for the app or not. When the notification is off I get to the Notification Settings of the system. The app is working fine when a user does only single input in the System Notification Settings but when the user turns ON and OFF again the settings, the app is behaving unusual.

> The application is changing with the SystemDefault theme.

Also, I am not getting any error messages in the Logcat.

The app is behaving as follows:

[image]

I have implemented as follows:

**When pressing the Switch**

```
 if (compoundButton.isChecked()) {


            if (NotificationManagerCompat.from(SettingActivity.this).areNotificationsEnabled()) {
                subscribeOffer();
            } else {
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
                        .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
                compoundButton.setChecked(false);
                startActivityForResult(settingsIntent, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        } else {
            unSubscribeOffer();
        }

}
```

**And onActivityResult**

```
if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        boolean isChecked = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).areNotificationsEnabled();
     

        if (isChecked) {
            subscribeOffer();
        } else {
            subscribeNotificationsButton.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
```